# pyttsx3 is conflicting with tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

My tkinter app will run console-free (`.pyw`) until I import pyttsx3. As soon as pyttsx3 is imported, the app will only run from the editor (Idle).

This is a tkinter app that runs perfectly when run from idle. I import pyttsx3, initialize it, have it speak using Windows Sapi voices, all is well, all tkinter functions operate as intended from start to finish. But outside of Idle, the app won't run in `.pyw` mode. It shows a black console screen for a brief moment and closes. I have checked very carefully - removing all pyttsx3 code from the app - except the import statement and, quite literally, the import statement alone is enough to cause the app to no longer run in `.pyw` mode.

```
import tkinter as tk
```

(runs fine in .pyw mode)

```
import tkinter as tk
import pyttsx3 as speak
```

(will not run in .pyw mode)

The question: how could simply importing a library (not even initializing or using it...just importing it) cause the tkinter app to no longer run as .pyw? Could importing a library somehow be interfering with the tkinter main loop?

Comment: Can you import and use `pyttsx3` from an interactive Python session?

Comment: I wrote an earlier interactive version of the app without tkinter. Went back to check, and in fact the issue is the same so it may be a python issue rather than tkinter. What I found:

Without pyttsx3:
- runs fine from idle (in shell)
- runs fine from .py file (in console)
- will not run from .pyw file

With pyttsx3:
- funs fine from idle
- will not run as a .py or .pyw file

Again, all that's required to disable the app is the import statement itself.

Comment: You should probably add that information to your question.

Comment: Do other Tkinter programs run from `.pyw` files without problems?

Comment: Yes, other tkinter programs run fine from .pyw including this app, as long as pyttsx3 is not imported.

Answer (score 0):

Good question. If I had to guess, something in the pyttsx3 library invokes a process that is unrelated to Python, for the purpose of text-to-speech conversion. Windows probably opens a Command Prompt window in such a case since that process runs independently.

Unless the pyttsx3 library has documentation for how to suppress this—after a cursory glance, I don't see such—then I would recommend [opening a new issue](https://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyttsx3/issues) with the package maintainer. <s>I believe that it would need to set the [`CREATE_NO_WINDOW` flag](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW) when being run on Windows.</s>

Comment: According to github's search function, `subprocess` is *not* used in `pyttsx3`...

Comment: @RolandSmith, that's interesting. I looked into it further and it appears that pyttsx3 uses [SAPI 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Speech_API) on Windows via the [pywin32 package](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32). I'm not familiar with that package, but the package maintainer of pyttsx3 seems to be familiar with it, so I still recommend that OP open a new issue with them. I assume that the desired change is still possible with the pywin32 package. I've removed the last sentence of my comment to reflect that the `subprocess` module isn't in play.

Comment: Many thanks - have opened a new issue. Will report back on what I find.